# ImportError: No module named Crypto - pycrypto

Tags: python, pycrypto

Here is the traceback is got when I ran fab on:prod deploy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fab", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Fabric==1.10.2', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 564, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2662, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2316, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    from fabric import api, state, colors
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/api.py", line 11, in <module>
    from fabric.decorators import (hosts, roles, runs_once, with_settings, task,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/decorators.py", line 9, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

I tried to solve my problem with many similar answer/question on stackoverflow, but nothing went well. So yes, I have already tried `pip install pycrypto`, `pip install Crypto` and also `pip install crypto`. How could I fix this issue?

```
pip install pycrypto
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto in ./venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

I am using a virtualenv and it is activated.

Answer (score 0):

Install it:

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Crypto` module, I know you have tried `pip install pycrypto`, but maybe your `pip` is for python 3? Try `pip2 install pycrypto` maybe.

Just saw your edit, you have installed pycrypto in a virtualenv but your frabic is not installed within the same virtualenv.

Comment: I modified my question ... no, pip = pip2 for me in this case

Comment: I think you need to remove frabic first, then install it in the same virtualenv. [When you do `/usr/bin/fab`, it uses the system python instead of the virualenv one, so if your system python (i.e. not the virualenv one has no pycrypto),  then it should throw that error.]

Comment: It is weird, because it kept from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and not from my virtualenv

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant, if you installed fabric in the virtualenv, `which fab` should return something like `/home/ryan/.virtualenvs/test/bin/fab` instead of `/usr/bin/fab`.